# An addition of non-existing **trailing** zeros at importing csv file by pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, formatting

Importing a .csv file given by

```
a
1.4
1.12
```

leads to an addition of a **trailing** zero in the first line. How to avoid it?

[image]

Comment: This is just the way that pandas formats the read in data when printed ... to make it look nice. The value is autodetected to be a np.float or somehting like that and when printing it it is formatted. From a numerical standpoint there is no difference between 1.4 and 1.40 or 00001.40000000000 ....

Comment: Your accepted answer forces the data type inside your _df_ to be a string. While this solves the immediate displaying issue, it creates plenty of other issues down the line if you want to do anything with the data you read. The correct way to fix this is setting the format string for floats when printing your dataframe. There are tons of questions on SO asking how to convert object-typed data in a df to work with it as numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the visual representation of the float data in your `df`. If you want it different, change the *format string* for it.

For your numbers `'{:,g}'` would work (see [format specification mini language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) - scroll down for the table that explains it).

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

with open("data.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("a\n1.4\n1.12")

df = pd.read_csv("data.txt")
print(df) 

# change the way floats are formatted
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.06f}'.format

# change the way floats are formatted
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,g}'.format

df = pd.read_csv("data.txt")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
# default formatting
      a
0  1.40
1  1.12


# {:,06f}
          a
0 1.400000
1 1.120000

# {:,g}
      a
0   1.4
1  1.12
```

From a numerical standpoint there is no difference between 1.4 and 1.40 or 00001.40000000000.

---

[Guarav Kumar's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66086155/7505395) to use

> ```
> df = pd.read_csv('minExamp.csv' , dtype = str)
> ```

is **bad advice** - it changes the data type for the (single) column to be of type string.

This will prevent you from calculating anything with the numbers of your dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.read_csv('minExamp.csv' , dtype = str)
```

Comment: I don't think so , but does it makes any difference if you will consider these zeroes.It balances decimal part in every row.

Comment: While but forcing the data type of the number to be string instead of a float will fix the output problem, you now have created plenty of problems down the road if you want to do anything with that number - very bad advice.